# Apache Permission for a bat file w/ Django

Tags: django, apache, permissions, batch-file

I have seen a lot of similar questions, but still i am failing.  I have win XP, Apache 2.2, Django 1.4, Python 2.7 and mod_wsgi 3.3.  All i am trying to do is when you hit the page the bat file executes and which echoes hi.  This works when i run it on the django internal dev server.  But when i got to Apache, it fails and in the error.log i get the message

> The system cannot write to the specified device.
>   
> The system cannot write to the specified device.
>   
> The system cannot write to the specified device.
>   
> The system cannot write to the specified device.
>   
> The system cannot write to the specified device.

I have not seen that error in many other places.  Most people seem to get "Permission denied".  I still think the permissions are wrong.  So when i run it is the django internal server i get in the console:

> Validating models...
>
> 0 errors found
>   Django version 1.4, using settings 'testsite.settings'
>   Development server is running at http:`//127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
>
> C:\Sites\cprm>echo hi 
>   
> hi
>   
> [18/Sep/2012 14:58:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 63

That seems fine.  The only thing throwing me off that I'm running from /testsite and not /cprm.  I could just cd .. before.  Anyway, so since in the internal server it is writing to the console, i guess i need to do the equivalent in apache.  I'm not sure where the apache console is.  I tried adding permission to the apache log file as that is where the error gets generated.  I'm not sure that is equivalent to the regular console.

My Apache file looks like this (ignore back ticks):

```
<`VirtualHost *>

ServerName http://example.com:80

WSGIScriptAlias /cprm "C:/sites/cprm/wsgi.py"
WSGIScriptAlias /testsite "C:/sites/testsite/wsgi.py"

<Directory "C:/sites">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

<`/VirtualHost>
```

My view just looks like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime, os

def home(request):
    os.system('C:/Sites/testsite/testsite/test.bat')
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

It's basically just a quick test I tried doing.

---

EDIT

Hi pacha.  Thanks for the response.  I have done some reading on the topic now.  So I made the changes you indicated.  My wsgi.py file looks like such:

> import os, sys
>
> path = 'C:/Sites/testsite'
>   
> if path not in sys.path:
>   
>     sys.path.append(path)
>
> os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testsite.settings")
>   
> sys.stdout = sys.stderr
>   
> print 'hi'
>   
> from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>   
> application = get_wsgi_application()

Then when i go to error.log, i do in fact see 'hi' printed.  So that is good.  However, the test.bat file w/ the echo hello does not execute and i still get the same message.  And thanks for the permission advice.  I am now no longer using virtual.  I am not ready for that yet.  Any other ideas for what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be related to how the standard output is handled. WSGI disables standard output by default. That's why your program works fine in the development server (which redirects the output to the terminal where the server was launched) but doesn't work with Apache.

You can enable stdout in WSGI using a configuration directive that you put in your virtual host conf file (together with the other WSGI directives):

```
WSGIRestrictStdout Off
```

However, take into account that Apache isn't associated to any terminal. If you want to see the output of your program then one thing you can do is to redirect the standard output to the standard error stream by adding this to your WSGI file:

```
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
```

Restart Apache an you should see any output of your application (or any child process, as it is your case) in the error.log file of Apache.

**Note**: Don't add the Apache log files directory to your virtual host configuration. You aren't granting permissions to Apache over those files but allowing *anyone* to see them, which is as you can imagine a non-trivial security risk.

---

**Update**

*Avoiding permission problems*

You may want to try to use WSGI in daemon mode. That way the web application can be executed under your username (much like when using the internal development server). In your case, the configuration directives should be something along the lines:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess site1 user=<USERNAME> group=<GROUP> processes=1 threads=1
WSGIScriptAlias /testsite "C:/sites/testsite/wsgi.py"

<Directory "C:/sites/testsite/">
    WSGIProcessGroup site1
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You have to substitute `<USERNAME>` and `<GROUP>` by your username and group in your Windows machine (it may work by just setting the username though). This is usually a nice way of avoiding permission issues since your application will be executed in a very similar way to how it is executed by the development server. (Notice that we're using just one process and one thread just to make Apache behave even more closely to how the development server does. You surely want to change those values in production to higher values).

You can check the daemon mode documentation [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess)

*Executing your script*

To call external program from Python code, the module `subprocess` is usually preferred over `os.system` calls. The former allows you to have much more control over how the new process has to be executed whereas the later just passes the call to the operating system.

You can try the `subprocess.check_output` function. It executes a script/program and allows you to capture its output:

```
print subprocess.check_output(['C:\Sites\testsite\testsite\test.bat'], shell=True)
```

It has the additional advantage that you can capture the output in a string variable. (Btw, you may or may not need the `shell=True` param in Windows when calling a bat script, I'm not sure about that).

Comment: Sure, there are a couple of things you can try. I have updated my answer with two easy ones. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Things to check**

1. Permissions  what are the user permissions on the file
   C:/Sites/testsite/testsite/test.bat?

Are they read for the same user that is running the Apache Process?

1. Have you installed python for all logged in users not just for?
2. Have you reviewed your Apache conf directives?
   User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
   It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
   running httpd, as with most system services.

   User carlos
   Group Administrators

Does that same user have permissions to read the file on the file system?

```
<Directory "C:/Sites/testsite/testsite/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```